# Expo: Can the app be single instance when launched

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am using the expo deep linking. Is it possible to load the same instance of the app instead of loading a new instance of the application.

Current App -> WebView loaded for login -> After authenticated -> it should go back to the same instance of the app. Instead of going to the same instance, it run a new instance.

Comment: Where are WebView loaded for login -> After authenticated  executed? Are they outside the app and do you use deeplinking for going to the app?

Comment: No is inside the app.. I need the web view to carry the session so once logged in I can create complex feature with webview.  It works fine when doing it in expo client instead of standalone app